# How to add an AssetBundle into cache from a file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

I have an AssetBundle on disk, a `string path` pointing to it and the `Hash128 bundleHash` of the bundle.

How can I move the AssetBundle from `path` into Unity's AssetBundle caching system?

I cannot use `UnityWebRequest.GetAssetBundle(path, hash, 0)` because of performance reasons on IOS

The `Caching` class does not seem to have any interface for doing this.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.LoadFromFile.html Read the note at the bottom.

Comment: what note? About checking the issue tracker?

Comment: `This is the fastest way to load an AssetBundle.` If your concern is speed of course.

Comment: oh, no I do not need to load the bundle into memory, I need to prime the cache for loading later